# Is there any way to undo the Ctrl + Shif + F in e-clipse without using Ctrl + Z

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to undo the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in e-clipse without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>!

Previously my code was like this :
cityCode = HotelSubList.item(h).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Code").getNodeValue();

After <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> it is like this.

cityCode = HotelSubList
.item(h)
.getAttributes()
.getNamedItem(
"Code")
.getNodeValue();

Now I need to convert the format as it was without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: Undo using Ctrl+Z seems to be the only way to reverse it. Any specific need why CTRL+Z should be avoided?

Comment: Accidently I have pressed Ctrl+Shift+F. Then I have done some modifications for the code. That's y I can't Ctrl+Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the code formatter settings from

`Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter`

and reformat your code with the new settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Eclipse's built-in history. If you want to change the whole document in one fell swoop, right click on the file in project explorer and select "Replace with" -> "Local History".

If you'd like to pick on choose which changes you want to keep and which to undo, right click on the file in project explorer and select "Compare with" -> "Local History". Choose the previous version you want to see side-by-side, and then for each difference detected you can select if you want to revert to the previous version or not.